# How to add values for reverse duplicate columns in a csv file by python

Tags: python, parsing, csv

I am new to Python and have a problem with my data. I have a csv file that has 3 columns. The first and the second columns are countries ISO codes and the third on is trade value between these countries. 
for Example:

```
col1  col2 col3
USA  FRA  1500*
USA  AUS  2000
FRA  GBR  1700  
FRA  USA  2000*
AUS  FRA  3000
GBR  DEU  4000
```

As you can see, the data is contained different trade value for both `USA FRA` and `FRA USA` but I want to get rid of these rows and have only `USA FRA` and the value would be the average of their 2 values (`(1500+2000)/2`)
which means:
At the end I want to save the results to a `csv` file that only a pair trade link is repeated once and the value be average of the values in the first csv file. something like this:

```
col1 col2 col3
USA  FRA  1750
USA  AUS  2000
FRA  GBR  1700
AUS  FRA  3000
GBR  DEU  4000
```

Thanks

Comment: OK, so... what's your question? Where's your code?

Answer (score 2):

Here is something to get you started. I'll leave the input parsing for you.

```
from collections import defaultdict
dd = defaultdict(lambda: [])  # default an array for the dictionary value

input = [  # TODO: populate input from csv
    [ 'USA', 'FRA', 1500 ],
    [ 'FRA', 'USA', 2000 ]
]

def make_key(v1, v2):  # sort the countries to find the keys
    return ''.join(sorted((v1, v2)))

for row in input:
    key = make_key(row[0], row[1])
    dd[key].append(row[2])  # append the value to the array


for k, v in dd.iteritems(): # TODO: write results to file
    print(k, sum(v) / 2)  # print average
```

Comment: at the end, I want to have a csv file with separate columns but if I follow your steps, I will come up with two columns

Comment: Adding a delimiter to line 10 is perfectly acceptable. `return ', '.join(sorted((v1, v2)))`

Answer (score 0):

I have to run, so I'm unable to comment much on my code (hopefully someone can else can edit that in), but this should get you started:

```
import csv

with open('input.csv') as infile:
    trades = {}
    for src, dest, val in csv.reader(infile, delimiter=' '):
        val = float(val)
        if dest in trades and src in trades[dest]:
            trades[dest][src].append(val)
            continue
        if src not in trades:
            if dest in trades:
                src, dest = dest, src
            else:
                trades[src] = {}
        if dest not in trades[src]:
            trades[src][dest] = []
        trades[src][dest].append(val)

with open('output.csv', 'w') as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter=' ')
    for src, d in trades.items():
        for dest, vals in d.items():
            writer.writerow([src, dest, sum(vals)/len(vals)])
```

This works:

**input.csv**

```
USA FRA 1500
USA AUS 2000
FRA GBR 1700
FRA USA 2000
AUS FRA 3000
GBR DEU 4000
```

**output.csv**

```
USA AUS 2000.0
USA FRA 1750.0
GBR DEU 4000.0
FRA GBR 1700.0
FRA AUS 3000.0
```

Comment: I think delimiter is space! and the `csv` has 2 field!

Comment: your code returns `TypeError: "delimiter" must be an 1-character string`

Comment: It does not work if we have added a country already. consider we have: AUS-- USA--1   ,AUS--GBR--1, USA--GBR--3 and USA--AUS--4 . By using this script you add both AUS--USA and USA--AUS because you have already added USA in the dictionary. I do not know how to modify it